# Multi-resolution favicons

Tags: html, favicon

Everyone in tutorialworld seems to be obsessed with CREATING multi-resolution .ico's to use as favicons.  My question, however, is what browser support for these multi-resolution .ico's is like.  Will the common browsers (Chrome, FF, Safari, and IE7+) treat an .ico containing two resolutions (16x16 and 32x32) in some sane way?  The consensus seems to be that going larger than 32x32 starts to bloat the file size without providing much benefit (except to IE9/Windows 7 and whatever they do with 64x64 images), at least.

Comment: If you like scripts, I wrote one to convert any image to a multi-resolution favicon using ImageMagick. http://blog.lavoie.sl/2012/11/multi-resolution-favicon-using-imagemagick.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of fairly good information on wikipedia, but not about size support specifically:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

However, I don't think most web browsers have a use case for an icon over 16x16. I certainly haven't seen a large icon, but I'm not surprised since larger icons would tend to expand url-bars, bookmarks and tabs to the point that they take up prohibitive amounts of vertical screen real-estate. I wouldn't bother until you knew somewhere it would be used and decide that the bandwith is worth it.

One thing to look into is whether or not they are utilized by any accessibility features for low vision users (this would make sense), but the screen shots here (for example):

http://www.accessfirefox.org/Firefox_Accessibility_Themes.php

seem to show the same old 16x16 icon despite the increased font size. I suspect the fact that one cannot rely on the existence of a 32x32 resolution means that nobody spends the time to program in code that looks for it.

As I understand it this multi-resolution feature for icons is intended to target reuse in "other contexts" such as [Prism](https://mozillalabs.com/en-US/prism/) (defunct) or [Air](http://www.adobe.com/products/air.html) (proprietary)

Comment: 32px and 64px favicons are primarily for saving bookmarks on the desktop etc, where the actual icon is larger.

Comment: @Truth, that's true, and it's also handy if you ever create anything that might be used offline. It's much easier to make a 32x32 icon at the same time you make the 16x16 icon then to try and derive it later.

Comment: Ah, I never save bookmarks to my (extremely cluttered) desktop :) Even so, then I guess it's a matter of OS support not browser support.

Comment: Actually, browsers *seem* to scale larger-resolution images so that they fit in the same space (but look better).  So there's definitely a use case for going above 16x16 - but once you do that it seems like you step into a morass of common but nonstandard solutions and a lack of consensus about best practices.